# MVC Set or Read View Components

Tags: mvc, view, update, controller

I often see the follwing example when reading about MVC (example is in Java, but question adapts to all OOP languages):

```
class View{
    JTextField tfName;

    public String getTfNameText(){
        return this.tfName.getText();
    }

    public void setTfNameText(String text){
        this.tfName.setText(text);
    }
}
```

And then in the Controller something like:

```
class Controller{
    View v = new View();
    ...
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        v.setTfNameText("Button Clicked!");
    }
    ...
}
```

But is this really considered good? Because as far as I understand for every GUI Component I have to add a get and set method and the Controller must know every of these methods, which makes it not very reusable. Can anyone tell me if this is the "correct"(i.e. an widely accepted) way of updating gui components in MVC?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your controller has to `import javax.swing.JTextField` you are doing it wrong.

You have a dependency on a package which your controller should know nothing about.

(Then your controller is not testable without integrating the UI, testing with a UI is a pain, etc etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this helps a lot with deciding if a aproach is good or not, but my initial question is still not answered, because the Controller in the Example only sets the Text (as String) for the JTextField and not the JTextField itself, but I still feel this aproach is bad.

Comment: I am not sure I follow.  If you do not want to have to invoke `v.setTfNameText()` from your controller, then the controller must either have a `JTextField tfName` member, or it must invoke `v.tfName.setText()`, and in both cases it would have to `import` `JTextField`, no?

Comment: Well I understand what you mean, the problem I have is the following: Im starting to learn about MVC and read so many different contrary articles about it and I don't really know whats considerd good and what not. The specific problem with the example above is that I `feel`like this is not very well scalable, but I don't know if there is any better approach or if this is the widely used way.

Comment: I see.  In this contrived example, the separation between the controller and the view appears trivial.  However, in real life scenarios, the interaction between the controller and the view is more involved, and the view does more than simply getting and setting values.  For example, if your control was a group of radio buttons, the view would simply expose an integer property, (getGender()/setGender()) so that the controller does not have to know anything about GUI stuff like radio buttons. See?

Comment: Ok, I understand, I always thought there was a better solution, but apperently there is not. Can you recommend any tutorials or further reading on MVC that teach the `correct` MVC?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot, since I am not very experienced with MVC myself.  As a matter of fact, given MVC's popularity, it surprises me that nobody more knowledgeable than me showed up to answer your question.  Perhaps wait until tomorrow, Monday?  Feel free to retract your "accept" decision from my answer, so as to increase the chances of your question being noticed tomorrow.  Also, add a comment tomorrow so as to "bump" your question in the list of active questions.